# Measure eccentricity of a polygon

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, geometry, polygons

I am trying to compute the eccentricity of a polygon in Mathematica.

I see that I can do something similar with `ComponentMeasurements`, but I am not sure how to get a `Graphics[Polygon[]]` expression to play nicely with it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
ComponentMeasurements[
 Graphics[
  Graphics[
   RegularPolygon[5]
   ]
  ]
 , "Eccentricity"]
```

However, I think you need to invert the colors. Using a test, you need:

```
ComponentMeasurements[
 Graphics[
  {White, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}
  , Background -> Black]
 , "Eccentricity"]
```

to get 0